# Magento 1.9 Google Custom Search Form - CSS Help

Tags: custom, css, search

Using Magento 1.9 with Google Custom Search - and RWD theme. Everything looks good on mobile, but when I resize the desktop window, the "GO" button on my search form gets cut off. I have tryed everything to figure out whats happening here. Can anyone help? Here is the link to the site to see the problem:

www.drmaxpowers.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your box is set to be a percentage of page width. The "Go" button is also set to be a percentage of this, so the width gets smaller with resizing, you could always set a min-width for your "Go" button... or just set a fixed px width.

You set a max width of 1260px to your header. But when resizing your search div (25%) gets smaller. And your "Go" button is 8% of this 25%

example 1 : 25% of page width = 300px, and 8% of 300px = 24px.
example 2 : 25% of page width = 260px, and 8% of 260px = 21px (aprox.)